# Json post on another domain using cxf

Tags: java, jquery, spring, cxf

im working on cxf web-service and i need to access data from another domain using ajax call..

my service method look like

```
 @POST
    @Path("/addService")
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Response addService(com.cyn.slon.model.dto.Service service) {
        log.debug("___          inside addService              ___");

       //business method call....

        return null;
    }
```

im using simple ajax call from another domain...

```
function test() {
     var jsonForServ = new Object();
     jsonForServ.name = "name1";
     jsonForServ.description = "descripnnnnn";
     jsonForServ.price = 20;
     alert(JSON.stringify(jsonForServ));
         $.ajax({
                url: "/Slon/services/bookservice/addService", 
                type: 'POST', 
                dataType: 'application/json;', 
                contentType: "application/json;",
                data: JSON.stringify(jsonForServ), processData:false,
                success: function(data) { 
                    alert('Success');
                },
                error:function(data,status,er) { 
                    alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
                }
        }); 
 }
```

im using jaxson to parse the json.. 
but it is not accessing the service method..

Comment: First try to access url using soapui  or restclient, it might be problem with firewall or etc

Comment: can i send the json data into service, is jsonp required???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spring framework doesn't support simple ajax call to invoke web service methods.

We can use jsonp that overrides the spring security.

But jsonp only supports post requests.

so it is not much convenient.

Another option is use a filter to avoid this.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/